# consul servers without LAN every server connected through wan

Tags: consul, service-discovery, nomad

im just getting started learning nomad and consul

i have several servers without a Local Area Network and they are connected through wam  (which i think you mean by datacenters) every server is a datacenter

i found in the docs https://www.consul.io/docs/architecture that each datacenter should have 3 to 5 consul servers so is my case applicable with consul and nomad

should i make all of the consul servers or 3 servers as consul and the rest are consul clients

Comment: Each Consul datacenter should have 3 servers for fault tolerance and scalability. Any physical servers within the DC can be configured run Consul agents in client mode. The Consul agents which are making connections over the WAN should all be configured as servers for their respective datacenter.

Comment: @BlakeCovarrubias so can i run all the consul agents as servers

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

> 3*consul servers or
>
> 2*consul clients and one server

I have every tested all these cases they work correctly